# How to show preview like in Twitter in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uipreviewaction

I'm working on `UIViewControllerPreviewing` in Objective-C, Peek and pop working fine but I need like Twitter 3D Touch like below Image, I mean I need options when we use 3D Touch.

[image]

But using `UIViewControllerPreviewing`, I'm unable to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this [UIContextMenuInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) - Use a `UIContextMenuInteraction` object to focus the user's attention on a specific portion of your content, and to provide actions for the user to perform on that content. A context menu interaction object tracks Force Touch gestures on devices that support 3D Touch, and long-press gestures on devices that don't support it.

Hope this helps!